# Looking for explanation of Erlang code book

Tags: erlang

Can someone please explain this line by line?

Many many thanks.

```
run() ->
        Pid = spawn(fun ping/0),
        Pid ! self(),
        receive
                pong -> ok
        end.
ping() ->
        receive
                From -> From ! pong
        end.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Line by line:

```
run() ->
```

Declare the function `run/0`

```
    Pid = spawn(fun ping/0),
```

Spawns new process with initialization function `ping/0` and store its pid to variable `Pid`

```
    Pid ! self(),
```

Sends message containing the pid of current process (result of `self/0` call) to the process which pid is stored in variable `Pid`

```
    receive
```

Waits for a message (or amount of time if there is after clause)

```
        pong -> ok
```

If there is a received message pong, return value `ok`

```
    end.
```

End of `receive` clause and dot also means there is end of function `run/0`

```
ping() ->
```

Declares the function `ping/0`

```
    receive
```

Waits for a message ...

```
        From -> From ! pong
```

When receiving *anything*, store it in variable `From` and then send message `pong` to the process determined by value in `From` (pid of process executing `run/0` function in this case)

```
    end.
```

End of receive and also `ping/0` function

Comment: What does -> mean exactly?

Comment: `->` is just delimiter. It typically delimits head and tail of some sort of clause. It delimits function head form body, case pattern head from its body, receive pattern form its body, `if` condition from its body and so.